# How to CAST datatype and also change value with CASE when creating MATERIALIZED VIEW? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, casting, case, materialized-views

I need to create a MATERIALIZED VIEW on a table. One of the columns is very problematic. I need to change its values and its datatype in the query. I'd like to ask you what is the fluent process for it when creating a matview?

I have a bunch of tables as an output of some decoding processes. To make these processes more effective I have to create e.g. test-queries (and several other stuffs not related here). Well, in summary, I need to create a MATERIALIZED VIEW of the tables as it is mentioned already. One of the columns has the wrong datas with the wrond type (returns TEXT instead of VARCHAR). Luckily I could decode them qiuckly but the type-casting is an other thing.

The problem is that with a lack of experiences I'm not able to find the correct way to change the values and the type at once! I aready had two solutions but they don't look very elegant:

1) I pre-created a table and altered the columns value after the SELECT section than I created the matview out of that table (it is slow and complicated for dozens of rows)

2) I CASTed the CASE statement itself in which I'm changing the values and closed it with END AS VARCHAR (it worked well except that the field names were gone from the matview and it made me very sad).

This way second_column left uncasted as TEXT:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS some_schema.some_matview AS
    (SELECT
        first_column,
        CASE
            WHEN second_column = '1' THEN 'A'
            WHEN second_column = '2' THEN 'B'
        END AS second_column,
        third_column,
    FROM base_schema.base_table);
```

This way second_column is probably casted as VARCHAR but no field names are visible in matview:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS some_schema.some_matview AS
    (SELECT
        first_column,
        CAST(CASE
            WHEN second_column = '1' THEN 'A'
            WHEN second_column = '2' THEN 'B'
        END AS VARCHAR),
        third_column,
    FROM base_schema.base_table);
```

I also tried some other presumably correct forms of the CAST-CASE constellation but all of them led me to different errors.

In summary: I need second_column to be casted as VARCHAR in my matview with the values of 'A' or 'B' instead of '1' or '2' which are TEXTs. The results I get don't match my expectations however they are more or less correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason why you can't alias the call to `CAST`:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS some_schema.some_matview AS
SELECT
    first_column,
    CAST(CASE
        WHEN second_column = '1' THEN 'A'
        WHEN second_column = '2' THEN 'B'
    END AS VARCHAR) AS second_column,    -- change here
    third_column,
FROM base_schema.base_table;
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you! That was my "Unexpected '{'" this time, I indicate.